# Wronskian of $y, y_1,\dots, y_n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $y_1,\dots, y_n$ be linearly independent functions in $C^\infty$. For each $y \in C^\infty$, define $T(y) \in C^\infty$ by
$$[T(y)](t)=\begin{vmatrix} y(t) & y_1(t) & \cdots & y_n(t)\\ y'(t) & y'_1(t) & \cdots &  y'_n(t) \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\y^{(n)}(t)&y^{(n)}_1(t)&\cdots&y^{(n)}_n(t)\end{vmatrix}$$
(a) Prove that $T:C^\infty \to C^\infty$ is a linear transformation.
(b) Prove that $N(T)=\operatorname{span}\{y_1, \dots, y_n\}$.

For (a), is it enough to show that $T(ax+y)=aT(x)+T(y)$?
And... for (b), that $N(T) =\{y:T(y)=0\}$?

Comment: What is the definition of $\,N(T)\,$ ?

Comment: I believe $N(T)$ is $\ker T$, indeed, in portuguese the word for kernel is "Núcleo" and some books insists in using the notation $N(T)$ for the kernel. The OP probably uses one of these books.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a) Yes linearity follows by multi-linearity of the determinant (that is, linearity with respect to one variable when the others are fixed) and linearity of the derivative.

(b) Recall that the determinant of a matrix is $0$ if and only if the columns are linearly dependent. So for each $t$ one can write $a(t)y(t)+\sum_{j=1}^nc_j(t)y_j(t)=0$. Now the fact that $y_1,\dots,y_n$ are linearly independent show that the function $a$ never vanishes.